# Finding minimal area of triangle with a fix point of hypotenuse

Tags: geometry, analysis, derivatives

There is a point *P* in (5;2) in a coordinate system, and there is an equation which goes through *P*. There are two other points: *A* and *B*: in *A*, the equation intersects the axle *y*, in *B* the equation intersects the axle *x* - so the *A* is (0;*a*) and the *B* is (*b*;0).

These 3 points determine a triangle: *O* (0;0), *A* (0;*a*) and *B* (*b*;0).

As you can see, the number of ***a***x+**b** equation can be infinity, the only criteria is it have to go through the point *P*.

How can I calculate the minimum area of the possible triangles?

Answer (score 2):

We can write the generic formula of a line as $\frac{x}{a} + \frac{y}{b} = 1$, this has the nice property that the intercepts are $(a, 0)$ and $(0, b)$ (which is the opposite to how you have them, but we're going to try to get rid of them soon enough anyway).

Since the point $P$ lies on the line, its coordinates must satsify the equation, i.e. $\frac{5}{a} + \frac{2}{b} = 1$, which gives us a relation between the two points.

So you want to minimise the area of the triangle $OAB$, which is $\frac{ab}{2}$, subject to the constraint above. There are a few ways to go about this, one of which is to just find an expression for the area in terms of $a$ and differentiate it to find the critical points.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll try to solve the issue with help of it.